# Faster Way To Transfer Video FIle

Tags: raspbian, networking, linux, ethernet, data-transfer

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian installed in it, and I would like to receive video files on My Ubuntu machine from Raspberry through a switch via Ethernet(CAT5).

Note: I can connect both devices together directly without switch.

I've tried a way:

Receive it by using this command

```
rsyc -rav pi@ IP python ~/
```

Worked okay but I feel that are extremely slow. For example, it takes about 37 minutes to receive a 4.7 GB video file.

Is there any faster way to receive files on Ubuntu machine from raspberry?

My case is different from this one
[Is there any way to send files to raspberry faster?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10137/is-there-any-way-to-send-files-to-raspberry-faster)

Answer (score 2):

37 minutes isn't an unreasonable amount of time for so much data.  That puts your average transmission rate at 16.9Mb/s

The raspberry pi has a 480Mb/s bus that's shared between both the ethernet and usb ports.  Once you include USB overhead (USB is really inefficient), rsync overhead, and the fact that you're both reading and (I assume) writing via this bus, it starts to make more sense.

Source: [RaspberryPi Forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=61730)

Answer (score 2):

where is your source file stored on the SD card (what type, what class), on an USB device?
to where do you copy... to a HDD?
what s the CPU, RAM and SD clock speed?

you RPi has to read the file data from local storage to its RAM via USB and then though ethernet, that is in fact also an USB device... even the USB 2.0 standard provides 480Mb/s there is some overhead.
100Mb/s ethernet does not mean, that you will reach the maximum speed... in reality it is more like up to 70% max, because there is also some overhead.
and depending of the kind of logical connection nfs, sshfs, samba, ftp, sftp, ... or what ever these protocolls has some overhest as well. - specially, if security encryption is used, it will slow down alot.
and the last is what file system is on the destination and how fragmented it is...
there are many variables, that can influence the overall transfere rate.
oh, and does your copy method simply copy or does it also veryfy the written data (write and then read and compare, if every thing was written correctly)